# Unable to send ajax post request to spring mvc controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-security

I am trying to send the ajax post request on button click,
My jsp form is

```
 <body>
 <form name="userForm" id="userForm"  method="POST">
  <table><tbody id="uniform">
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rashi</td>
    <td><input name="rashi" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Gothram</td>
    <td><input name="gothram" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Gender</td>
    <td><input name="gender" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    
    <td><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="addProfile()">Add</button></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </form></body>
```

the function in js i.e.,addProfile() is,

```
    function addProfile(){
    alert("inside profile");
    $.ajax({
    url: "saveUser",
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData(this), // Data sent to server
    contentType: false, // The content type used when sending data to the server.
    cache: false, // To unable request pages to be cached
    processData:false,  // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
    success: function(data){
        alert(${profile_id});
            if(data=="registered"){}
            
    },
    error: function(){}             
     });
     }
```

My controller code is,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void insert(ModelMap model, Principal principal,HttpSession session,@ModelAttribute @Valid Profile profile,
         BindingResult result) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(" inside insert  ");
    
   System.out.println("profilec name"+profile.getName());
   System.out.println(result.getErrorCount());
   int profile_id=service.Insert(profile);
    model.addAttribute("profile_id",profile_id);
   }
```

spring-security file is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

   <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
    <security:http auto-config="true" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" /> 
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/login"/>
    
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index"
        authentication-failure-url="/fail2login" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />

   </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
  <!-- <security:password-encoder ref="encoder" /> -->
    <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query=
                "select username,password, enabled from USER_MASTER where username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query=
                "select username,USER_ROLE from USER_ROLE where username =?  " />
                            
    </security:authentication-provider>
  
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="encoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg name="strength" value="10" />
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

And I am getting that 405 error even i remove that ajax code,like this

```
function addProfile(){
    alert("inside profile");
   
     }
```

I am getting alert,but then after I am getting the error code,

[image]

My profile bean class is,

```
public class Profile {

private String name;


private String rashi;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getRashi() {
    return rashi;
}

public void setRashi(String rashi) {
    this.rashi = rashi;
}

public String getGothram() {
    return gothram;
}

public void setGothram(String gothram) {
    this.gothram = gothram;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

private String gothram;

private String gender;
 }
```

what could be the reason for 405-method not allowed?

Comment: is your page refreshes ? If yes your form is getting submit no ajax call is intiated .

Comment: *I am getting 405 error even when I remove the ajax code* - then it's *(clearly)* not the ajax POST that's causing the 405.  Look closely in the browser network tab to find exactly what *is* causing the 405.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your `form` that is POSTing after your `addProfile()` call.

Your button is

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="addProfile()">
```

without `type=` the default is `type=submit` so your button causes the form to submit to the form's URL, which, not set, will be the same as page's url and it's *this* (page) url that's giving the 405.

The simplest solution is to change your button to

```
<button type='button' class="btn btn-default" onclick="addProfile()">
```

so that it doesn't submit the form.

---

Other Options:

You could

- change onclick to `onclick="addProfile();return false;"`

or

- `onclick="return addProfile();` *and* `return false` from addProfile() (after the `$.ajax({});`)

or (preferred)

- use jquery to bind your events and return false from the submit attempt